# An exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.FailedToPerformActionOnHiddenControlException'

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Im getting the following error when I run the coded UI application:

**An exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.FailedToPerformActionOnHiddenControlException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll but was not handled in user code**

This exception arises in the Mouse.Click() function in the below code.

```
public static void DestinationMaster()
    {
        Mouse.Hover(PPI.PPIHome.PPI_Main.PPI_Window.MastersPane);
        Mouse.Click(PPI.PPIHome.PPI_Main.PPI_Window.DestinationMasterPane.DestinationMasterHyperlink);
    }
```

The application doesnt run after this exception.I am using IE 8 as my browser to run the application.But when I run the application ,IE mode is changed automatically to compatibility mode.Is this related to the exception?
Is there a way to resolve this issue and get my application to running.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you visually confirm that the link is not being blocked by a popup, dropdown, etc? What are you doing before this code? A waitforcontrolready might help. Do you have the latest updates for VS as there have been some issues fixed with a new update.

Comment: Im sure there is no pop up block or a dropdown.Before the Mouse.click() method call ,Im using the following code:                                               Browser.LaunchAndNavigate(AppConfig.GetValue("URL"));
                Mouse.Hover(PPI.PPIHome.PPI_Main.PPI_Window.MastersPane);                      to navigate to the url and go to the home page.I don't have the latest updates of VS.Im using VS2012.

Comment: Rather than VS2013, by latest I meant the latest patches and updates for VS2012. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305

Comment: Thank you @yonitdm,                                                  My application runs now.The issue was with the URL. When I used the Server url (Testing environment url) to run my test scripts ,the exception was thrown.But,when I changed the URL to my local host url(Development environment url) ,the application run.Temporary fix though.

Answer (score 0):

Does the hover work? Can you hover over the link instead to make sure that works? What happens when you find the control from the UIMap?

What does `PPI.PPIHome.PPI_Main.PPI_Window.DestinationMasterPane.DestinationMasterHyperlink.TryGetClickablePoint()` return?

Does the UI need to scroll to see the link? If so you could use `PPI.PPIHome.PPI_Main.PPI_Window.DestinationMasterPane.DestinationMasterHyperlink.EnsureClickable()` to scroll to the control.

Try to use `WaitForControlReady()` to make sure the page is fully loaded before coded ui acts on it. Sometimes coded ui can move faster than the application under test.

Make sure you have the latest [update for VS2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305)